# Eclipse JSHint plugin issue

Tags: eclipse, jshint

JSHint working fine from the CLI (W7 OS with Git Bash)

Have Eclipse Kepler SR2
Just installed JSHint from Marketplace
Went to Project --> Properties... set firstly *.js (all files)... Apply
Result: did not pick up this line or signal it in any way (when the line was added):

```
if( app.thing == null ) console.log( 'bleat!' );
```

then set all files... Apply
Result: did not pick up the line (when entered).

Anyone got an idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: OK, but what *should* it be doing that it's not doing?

Comment: should be saying "===" for the null test... that's what it does in the CLI context...